# How to create manifest.json dynamically for Universal Viewer

Tags: c#, manifest.json, jpeg2000, iiif

I am working on showing Universal Viewer from my .Net web application.
I have many JP2 images stored in IIP Image server.
Now, I want to create manifest.json to feed my Universal Viewer.
Is it possible to create it dynamically with canvases for all the images stored in image server.
Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Where are stored your metadata? The iiif manifests are built mainly with metadada, not with images (except the size and the name).

Answer (score 0):

The IIIF [International Image Interoperability Framework] API defines a web service that returns an image in response to a standard HTTP or HTTPS request. The URI may indicate the area, size, rotation, quality characteristics and format of the requested image.

For a server, you can deploy your own server, such as a Loris server or IIPImage

Comment: Sorry, this is not the specific answer of my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For IIIF presentation API 2.0 and earlier versions there is this excellent tool for Python [iiif-prezi](https://github.com/iiif-prezi/iiif-prezi) which is a reference implementation. Maybe you can use IronPython for using it in your C# project. Basically, you create a manifest object:

```
manifest = factory.manifest(label="Example Manifest")
seq = manifest.sequence()  # unlabeled, anonymous sequence
```

And then you can add the canvases dynamically:

```
for p in range(10):
    # Create a canvas with uri slug of page-1, and label of Page 1
    cvs = seq.canvas(ident="page-%s" % p, label="Page %s" % p)

    # Create an annotation on the Canvas
    anno = cvs.annotation()

    # Add Image: http://www.example.org/path/to/image/api/p1/full/full/0/native.jpg
    img = anno.image("p%s" % p, iiif=True)

    # Set image height and width, and canvas to same dimensions
    imagefile = "/path/to/images/p%s.jpg" % p
    img.set_hw_from_file(imagefile)
```

## API 3.0

I built my own Python module for dealing with 3.0 IIIF presentation API which is called [IIIFpres](https://github.com/giacomomarchioro/pyIIIFpres), you might consider giving it a try:

```
from IIIFpres import iiifpapi3
iiifpapi3.BASE_URL = "https://iiif.io/api/cookbook/recipe/0009-book-1"
manifest = iiifpapi3.Manifest()
manifest.set_id(extendbase_url="manifest.json")
manifest.add_label("en","Simple Manifest - Book")
manifest.add_behavior("paged")

data = (("Blank page",3204,4613,"https://iiif.io/api/image/3.0/example/reference/59d09e6773341f28ea166e9f3c1e674f-gallica_ark_12148_bpt6k1526005v_f18","/full/max/0/default.jpg"),
        ("Frontispiece",3186,4612,"https://iiif.io/api/image/3.0/example/reference/59d09e6773341f28ea166e9f3c1e674f-gallica_ark_12148_bpt6k1526005v_f19","/full/max/0/default.jpg"),
        ("Title page",3204,4613,"https://iiif.io/api/image/3.0/example/reference/59d09e6773341f28ea166e9f3c1e674f-gallica_ark_12148_bpt6k1526005v_f20","/full/max/0/default.jpg"),
        ("Blank page",3174,4578,"https://iiif.io/api/image/3.0/example/reference/59d09e6773341f28ea166e9f3c1e674f-gallica_ark_12148_bpt6k1526005v_f21","/full/max/0/default.jpg"),
        ("Bookplate",3198,4632,"https://iiif.io/api/image/3.0/example/reference/59d09e6773341f28ea166e9f3c1e674f-gallica_ark_12148_bpt6k1526005v_f22","/full/max/0/default.jpg"),)

for idx,d in enumerate(data):
    idx+=1 
    canvas = iiifpapi3.Canvas()
    canvas.set_id(extendbase_url=["canvas","p%s"%idx]) # in this case we use the base url
    canvas.set_height(d[2])
    canvas.set_width(d[1])
    canvas.add_label("en",d[0])
    annopage = iiifpapi3.AnnotationPage()
    annopage.set_id(extendbase_url=["page","p%s"%idx,"1"])
    annotation = iiifpapi3.Annotation(target=canvas.id)
    annotation.set_id(extendbase_url=["annotation","p%s-image"%str(idx).zfill(4)])
    annotation.set_motivation("painting")
    annotation.body.set_id("".join(d[3:]))
    annotation.body.set_type("Image")
    annotation.body.set_format("image/jpeg")
    annotation.body.set_width(d[1])
    annotation.body.set_height(d[2])
    s = iiifpapi3.service()
    s.set_id(d[3])
    s.set_type("ImageService3")
    s.set_profile("level1")
    annotation.body.add_service(s)
    # remember to add the item to their container!
    annopage.add_item(annotation)
    canvas.add_item(annopage)
    manifest.add_item(canvas)

manifest.json_save("manifest.json")
```